# configure LEXIK JWT AUTHENTICATION BUNDLE

Tags: symfony

I am getting this error when i am trying to configure LEXIK JWT AUTHENTICATION BUNDLE how i can fix it.

> FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 133: There is no
>   extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path"
>   (in
>   /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "jwt_private_key_path", found "framework",
>   "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine",
>   "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_mongodb",
>   "lexik_jwt_authentication", "fos_rest", "debug", "web_profiler",
>   "sensio_distribution" in
>   /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml
>   (which is being imported from
>   "/var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/config.yml").
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "jwt_private_key_path" (in
>   /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "jwt_private_key_path", found "framework",
>   "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine",
>   "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_mongodb",
>   "lexik_jwt_authentication", "fos_rest", "debug", "web_profiler",
>   "sensio_distribution"

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this [link](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation) can help you

Generate the SSH keys :

```html
$ mkdir -p config/jwt # For Symfony3+, no need of the -p option
$ openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
$ openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem
```

In case first openssl command forces you to input password use following to get the private key decrypted

```html
$ openssl rsa -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/private2.pem
$ mv config/jwt/private.pem config/jwt/private.pem-back
$ mv config/jwt/private2.pem config/jwt/private.pem
```

**configuration:**

Configure the SSH keys path in your config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```html
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' 
    public_key:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'  
    pass_phrase:      'your_secret_passphrase' 
    token_ttl:        3600
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what happens when you don’t add the bundle to `AppKernel`. Adding the line ...

```
new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),
```

... to the array of bundles in method `registerBundles()` in `app/appKernel.php` should fix the problem.

Comment: i have been added  new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),in AppKernal.inside the Array but  still l am getting same error when i am trying to execute ..

Comment: In prod or env environment? If prod: did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

We need to write `parameters.yml` as:

```
parameters:
   jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' # ssh private key path
   jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'  # ssh public key path
   jwt_key_pass_phrase:  ''                                         # ssh key pass phrase
   jwt_token_ttl:        3600
```